# Quick javascript hover question

Tags: javascript, css, tumblr

I have a quick JavaScript question. I was wondering if there's a way to make a div called `#post li span` to show up (appear) when you hover over the div "#post li" ? It'd mean a lot if someone could provide me with a code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older IE's you won't have access to the :hover pseudo class on none anchor tags.  so you can use javascript like this:

```
$('#post li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('span').show();
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find('span').hide();
  }
);
```

check out [jQuery hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) for more info on how it works

Answer (score 4):

You can do that directly with CSS:

```
#post li span {
    display: none;
}

#post li:hover span {
    display: inline;
}
```

If you want to use JavaScript and have jQuery, you can use:

```
$('#post li span').hide();
$('#post li').hover(
    function() { $('span', $(this)).show(); },
    function() { $('span', $(this)).hide(); }
);
```

If you want to use JavaScript and don't have jQuery, things start getting more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS.
Apply `display: none` to `#post li span`, then add `display:block` for `#post li:hover span`